# how to properly show / hide UIView on button click in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have a `UIView`, added in my xib file. Through connection inspector join it properly.

In `viewDidLoad:` method I am hiding it and on some button pressed showing it.

Here is my code so far:

*.h file*

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView   *subView;
```

in `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
_subView.hidden = YES;
```

It is hiding this view properly, but on button pressed it is not showing up.

```
- (IBAction)customerInvoice:(id)sender
{
//self->_subView.hidden = NO;
_subView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Using both ways it is not showing up. Please, help me to resolve it.

Comment: Are you sure customerInvoice: action fired when you press the button? Add NSLog to make sure it's fired.

Comment: You could also put a breakpoint into the event handler just to check that the code is being hit. This will also allow you to check the value of the _subView in case for some reason it is or has become nil.

Comment: @Greg yes i checked this

Comment: @Stuart what you are saying, it should be nil or not?

Comment: _subView UIView *  0x08c30630 …. set break point and it gives this value

Comment: Try to log `[_subView isDescendantOfView:[self view]]`

Comment: Try using Reveal to see what is happening with your views, http://revealapp.com it might help identify the issue

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi not showing

Comment: @Zaibi what is not showing? Did you logged it?

Comment: I tried this code and it works fine for me (with _subView.hidden). Remove all connection, IBOutlets and IBAction and add it back again.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi you mean NSLog?

Comment: Yes @Zaibi use `NSLog` to log the value

Comment: First you don't want to retain IBOutlet, it is not your property its  IBs so you can write weak instead of retain, second you don't need _, just @synthesize subView; and use it without _...Third try not hiding the view in viewDidLoad, just to see if you are really doing the hiding or smth. else is wrong

Comment: @Greg your trick works for me.. i just remove the connection and connect it back, now its working perfectly….

Comment: Would you like me to add it as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime you (or xCode) can make mistake during connecting IBOutlets/IBAction so if it doesn't work you can remove connection and it back again, mostly it should help.

Also Apple recommendation is use weak instead of strong/retain for IBOutlet property so if you haven't got a good reason you should do:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *subView;
```

Answer (score 0):

First Declare view:

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *select_image_uiview;
```

Button Click Action:

```
   - (IBAction)cancel_choose_view:(id)sender
 {
    _select_image_uiview.hidden=YES;
   }
```